# Can CPU(like Intel/AMD/ARM) do higher math computation except for addition/subtraction/multiplication/division?

Tags: scipy, arm, hardware, intel, computation

I learn something about logical circuit and computer architecture,including assembly instruction set(such as x86 instruction set,ARM instruction set) and microarchitecture(x86/ARM),I found no matter Intel processor or ARM processor can only do addition/subtraction/multiplication/division these four basic math computation hardwarely,because Intel/ARM processor only have adder/subtracter/multiplier/divider these four basic computers.
But these processors support more advanced math computation like trigonometric function,exponential function,power function and these functions' derivative/ definite integral？Even  matrix computation？
I know these advanced math computations can be done softwarely(like Python's NumPy/SciPy),but Intel/ARM processor can support these advanced math computations hardwarely just like addition/subtraction/multiplication/division?

Comment: I'm not aware of any derivative / integral type functions. Matrix Multiply could be sped up using parallel math such as GPU or SIMD, but the processors you've listed don't have true vector operations like those found on some super computers that can perform a pipelined (enough staging and math units to keep up with memory bandwidth) multiply of a column by a row and sum the product.

Comment: @rcgldr Intel says their processor(i3/i5/i7)have`FCOS`,`FSIN`module,just like `ADDER`

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you *can* build hardware structures to help accelerate the calculation of things such as trigonometric functions. However, in practice, it's pointless, because it's not a good use of hardware resources.

There is a paper from 1983 on how trigonometric functions were implemented on the 8087 floating-point co-processor ([Implementation of transcendental functions on a numerics processor](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0165607483901515)). Even there, they rely on a [CORDIC implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC), which is a method of calculating trig functions using relatively basic hardware (add/sub/shift/table look-up). You can read more about CORDIC implementations in the following paper: [Evaluating Elementary Functions in a Numerical Coprocessor Based on Rational Approximations](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee486/doc/koren1990.pdf)

On a modern x86 processor, complex instructions like `FCOS` are implemented using [microcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode). Intel doesn't like to talk about their microcoded instructions, but you can find a paper from AMD right now that describes this particular use of microcode: [The K5 Transcendental Functions](https://software.intel.com/system/files/f1/54/cp_1995-04.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Intel processors do support trigonometric and many advanced computations

According to "Professional Assembly Language" by Richard Blum

Since 80486 the Intel IA-32 platform has directly supported floating point operations.

The FPU Floating Point Unit supports many advanced functions other than simple add, sum, multiple, div. 
They are

Absolute value FABS
Change sign FCHS
Cosine FCOS
Partial Tangent FPTAN
etc.